# Programmatically setting an image field from hook_node_insert (drupal 7)

Tags: 7, media

I have a content type that has a file field (which accepts only .zip file) and a screenshot which is an image field and is not displayed on the content submission form.  Instead I have a module that unzips the .zip file from hook_node_insert.  At this point I would also like to set the screenshot to be a .png extracted from the .zip file.  So far I have had no success and I always seem to get an error like this:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '463' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {node} (nid, vid, type, language, title, uid, status, created, changed, comment, promote, sticky, tnid, translate, uuid) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
```

Since I was having trouble getting this to work, I tried what I thought might be simpler, I.E. trying to set the node to some image from the web using code like this:

```
  $image = file_get_contents('http://drupal.org/files/druplicon.large_.png');
  $file  = file_save_data($image, 'public://drupalicon.png',FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
  $node->field_screenshot[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['fid'] = $file->fid;
  node_save($node);
```

but I always get the integrity constraint problem listed above.  Could my problem be related to trying to do this from hook_node_insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node_save()` actually invokes `hook_node_insert()` so calling it from inside that hook probably isn't the best idea (I'm surprised you don't get out of memory errors doing that actually).

Instead you might want to use [`hook_node_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7), which is called before the node and associated data is committed to the database:

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  $image = file_get_contents('http://drupal.org/files/druplicon.large_.png');
  $file  = file_save_data($image, 'public://drupalicon.png',FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
  $node->field_screenshot[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['fid'] = $file->fid;
}
```

That way you won't have to call `node_save()` so you won't get the error, and the field data will save with the node as normal.

As `hook_node_presave()` is called for both inserts and updates, you might want to add a condition in there to check whether the node is new or not (checking `$node->nid` will probably suffice). Otherwise you'll end up doing this operation every time the new node is subsequently saved.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I was stuck on that for awhile and thought it might have something to do with the hook I was calling it from.  Also, checking if the fid is empty also seems to work to make this only happen the first time you save!